# How do I add Access data types with new fields I import from Excel?

Tags: excel, ms-access, types, import

I want to build Access tables from Excel worksheets.  I only want to build the structure, not populate with data.  I have (at least) two challenges:

1) I want to import the field names and the data types for each field name.

2) I would like to import to new tables and to existing tables.  I can import the fields only to a new table.  When I attempt to import to an existing table using the import wizard stating I have field names, the field names end up being used as data.  I can export the existing table to Excel, add my field names and import to a new table.  But I still don't have a way to include the data types.

My data types are short text with between 10 and 100 elements.  No other data properties are required.

Comment: Import uses first few rows to determine data types. Your question is too broad and there is no code provided for analysis and therefore not appropriate for SO.

Comment: Ben,  Thank you.  Yes, there is not code, that is what I am looking for.  So far, this is all menu driven.  Build a list of columns in Excel and import them via Access menu commands.

Comment: Why? Why not just build table in Access? Why involve Excel? SO is not a code writing service. You have not make any attempt at a solution and no code is provided for analysis. When import to existing table with wizard, column headers are not used as data. Don't know why you get different.

Comment: Ben,  
Thank you.  Yes, there is no code, that is what I am looking for.  So far, this is all menu driven.  Build a list of columns in Excel, save file, and import them via Access menu commands.  I can import the field names into a new Access table.  I could place one row of example data for each of my hundreds of field names, for each of hundreds of tables.  I would like a sustainable solution.  I would like to find some method to use code to build the fields and data types.  I can automatically analyze my Excel data to characterize the definition of Access data types.

Comment: I would like to build the tables in Access but there is so much structure, I am looking for a method to automate.  I have not found any code examples for doing this.

Comment: I am not Ben. This automation can be done in Access. I have a procedure that builds table but actually never use it. User enters field names and field property info into a table and this table (instead of external worksheet) is source for VBA procedure to build a table. Some table properties require DAO TableDefs to modify.

Comment: Perhaps the following will give you ideas https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/access/tables/

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.